# Disable Compression During JWrapper Builds

Tags: compression, jwrapper

JWrapper spends a significant amount of time compressing files. Is it possible to switch off the compression phase so the cycle trialling different JWrapper deployments (using various JRE's) could be faster?

If it is not currently possible, is this an option that could be added?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the option:

```
<Pack200Effort>0</Pack200Effort>
```

in your JWrapper XML to disable a lot of the compression in JWrapper.  This should speed up both builds and extraction.

**Note** though that this won't apply to your JREs unless you set the option but also delete the JRE archive from your build folder.  JWrapper will then rebuild the JRE archive from scratch using your options which will take some time the first time but subsequent builds and unarchives will be faster.

If you want to use a different build for the trial version you can just use a different jwrapper XML that uses a different build folder (and therefore has a different set of cached JRE archives).